# Same command in linux terminal execute different thing

Tags: text-processing

I want to create a smaller version from;

example

```
PRODUCTID   PRODUCTNDC  NDCPACKAGECODE  PACKAGEDESCRIPTION  STARTMARKETINGDATE  ENDMARKETINGDATE    NDC_EXCLUDE_FLAG    SAMPLE_PACKAGE
0002-0800_b02ed630-6947-431a-a8c8-227571403941  0002-0800   0002-0800-01    1 VIAL in 1 CARTON (0002-0800-01)  > 10 mL in 1 VIAL    19870710        N   N
```

into

```
b02ed630-6947-431a-a8c8-227571403941    0002-0800-01    1 VIAL in 1 CARTON (0002-0800-01)  > 10 mL in 1 VIAL    19870710        N   N
```

I use the command

```
 sed 's/^\([^_]*\)_\([^  ]*\)    \([^    ]*\)    \([^(]*\)[(][^)]*[)]/\2\t\4/' package.txt
```

I check from history because I typed the same thing before and when i copy paste it, it is different from when i use the same command from history. Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: I take it some of those spaces are the result of their being TAB characters which for a terminal is a control character that tells it to move to the next tabulation stop. So what we're seeing is the whitespace that happened to be there, and that's those spaces that you copied, not the TAB character which has no visual representation in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use `awk` for this

- Remove `PRODUCTNDC`
- Strip `PRODUCTNDC` from beginning of `PRODUCTID`
- Remove header line
- Assume tab-separated fields

So,

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR>1 { OFS=FS; $1=substr($1,length($2)+2,length($1)); $2=$3; $3=$4; $4=$5; $5=$6; $6=$7; $7=$8; NF--; print }'
```

Output

```
b02ed630-6947-431a-a8c8-227571403941    0002-0800-01    1 VIAL in 1 CARTON (0002-0800-01) > 10 mL in 1 VIAL     19870710                N       N
```